# How to apply new line in docx file generation using DOCX4J

Tags: java, file, newline, documentation-generation, docx4j

By the tutorials that I have seen. I learned how to add text on generating a docx file. but then Every time I add a line of text. I noticed that there is always a space between the first line of text and the second line of text. just like hitting the enter key twice. I know that the main cause is that everytime I add a line of text, I use a paragraph. and a paragraph starts with a space after another paragraph.

This is how I add a text

```
ObjectFactory factory;
factory = Context.getWmlObjectFactory();
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();
P spc = factory.createP();
R rspc = factory.createR();
rspc.getContent().add(wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().createParagraphOfText("sample"));
spc.getContent().add(rspc);

java.io.InputStream is = new java.io.FileInputStream(file);
wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addObject(spc);
```

so this code successfully runs and produces the right output. but when i add another paragraph. or text. i want it to be just under the first line of text. is there any way that i can add a simple line of text without using a paragraph? thanks in advance

EDIT: I've also tried adding a simple org.docx4j.wml.Text like this

```
Text newtext = factory.createText();
newtext.setValue("sample new text");
wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addObject(newtext);
```

the program will run but when i open the generated docx file, it will just prompt a message saying that there are problem with the contents.

Comment: If you did want to use paragraphs, you could control the space before and after.  You can set this on the paragraph or on a paragraph style, or in docdefaults in the styles part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The below will code will generate out put as line by line.

Key is here add Text(1) ->paragraph1 and Br ->paragraph1  after Text(2) ->paragraph1

`Br` is element like `Text` and `P`. by using this we can go for new line.

```
ObjectFactory factory = Context.getWmlObjectFactory();
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage
        .createPackage();

P spc = factory.createP();
R rspc = factory.createR();

Text t1 = factory.createText();
t1.setValue("tset");
rspc.getContent().add(t1);
Br br = factory.createBr(); // this Br element is used break the current and go for next line
rspc.getContent().add(br);
Text t2 = factory.createText();
t2.setValue("\r\n tset2");
rspc.getContent().add(t2);

spc.getContent().add(rspc);

wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addObject(spc);

wordMLPackage.save(new java.io.File("helloworld.docx"));
```

**OUTPUT:**

tset

tset2

Comment: tip: `org.docx4j.wml.ObjectFactory factory = Context.getWmlObjectFactory();`, once there are several different `ObjectFacotry` in the `org.docx4j` package

Comment: hello, I just tested your code and `t2.setValue("\r\n tset2");` won't return line break.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ObjectFactory.createBr()` to create a new line ending.

```
    ObjectFactory factory = Context.getWmlObjectFactory();

    R run = factory.createR();

    Text text1 = factory.createText();
    text1.setValue("asd");
    run.getContent().add(text1);

    Br nl = factory.createBr();
    run.getContent().add(nl);

    Text text2 = factory.createText();
    text2.setValue("efg");
    run.getContent().add(text2);

    P para = factory.createP();
    para.getParagraphContent().add(run);

    WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage =
            WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();
    wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addObject(para);

    wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addParagraphOfText("p1");
    wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addParagraphOfText("p2");

    wordMLPackage.save(new File("test.docx"));
```