# docx4j - new line in paragraph

Tags: docx4j

```
protected P createNormalParagraph(String text) {
    P p = factory.createP();
    R r = factory.createR();
    PPr ppr = factory.createPPr();
    PPrBase.Spacing space = new PPrBase.Spacing();
    space.setLine(BigInteger.valueOf(270));
    ppr.setSpacing(space);
    PPrBase.PStyle pStyle = factory.createPPrBasePStyle();
    pStyle.setVal(WordStyle.NORMAL);
    ppr.setPStyle(pStyle);
    p.setPPr(ppr);
    p.getContent().add(r);
    Text  t = factory.createText();
    t.setSpace("preserve");
    t.setValue(text);
    r.getContent().add(t);
    return p;
}
```

Suppose if I am getting a text value like - 
"Hi, This is xyz. I have
1. Pen.
2. Car.
3. Home."
but it is printing like -
"Hi, This is xyz. I have
 1. Pen. 
2. Car. 
3. Home."
How can I print with separate lines?

Comment: Is this question about how to add a soft return, about parsing the string and deciding where to insert the soft return (<w:br/>), or about using numbering?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42436211/docx4j-line-breaks-in-a-string and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16029743/how-to-apply-new-line-in-docx-file-generation-using-docx4j and see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44135393/docx4j-insert-a-line-break